# Conflicting inflection point conditions in my book

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

My 12th grade calculus book mentions that an inflection point is a point that:

> • Function $f$ in point $(c, f(c))$ has a tangent line.

> • Function $f$'s concavity shall change at point $(c, f(c))$.

Although this has been mentioned, in an example, it says that function $\sqrt[3]x$ has an inflection point at $x = 0$.

We know that $\sqrt[3]x$'s derivative is: $1/(3\sqrt[3](x^2))$ that at point $x = 0$ would not be possible and it would be a `Vertical Tangent`. Now, I understand that `Vertical Tanget` is a tangent line for our function but it's not in our derivative's domain.

I believe that my problem is with understanding the meaning of an available tangent line cause I thought that if a point has a tangent line, it's probably in the derivative's domain and as a `Vertical Tangent` wouldn't be available at our target point, the first condition wouldn't be satisfied.

What am I missing here?

Now based on this, if we say that a function has a tanget line at a certain point, it's possible that the specified point isn't in the derivative's domain, is that correct?

Comment: "Has a tangent" is not the same as "has a tangent that has a well-defined slope". The domain of the derivative is the set of all points where the function has a tangent **and** the tangent is not vertical. You yourself use the word "probably", which should be understood here to mean "it is not certain that" (as opposed to "provably", as in "we can prove that..."). That means that there may be points $(c,f(c))$ in the graph of $y=f(x)$ where (i) $f'(c)$ is not defined; but (ii) nonetheless the function has a tangent at $(c,f(c))$. Namely, those where the tangent is vertical.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Understood! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The *curve* $x\mapsto\bigl(x,\sqrt[3]x\bigr)$ has a tangent line at $(0,0)$, which is the $y$-axis. The fact that $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]x$ is not differentiable at $0$ is not relevant. In general, the graph of a function $f$ has a *non-vertical* tangent line at a point $\bigl(a,f(a)\bigr)$ if an only if $f$ is differentiable at $a$. But when the graph of $f$ has a *vertical* tangent line at a point $\bigl(a,f(a)\bigr)$, then $f$ is *never* differentiable at $a$.